# SQL Where Clause, how do I make it so the 1st condition is dependent to the other condition

Tags: mysql

How can I make it so 2 Where conditions can be dependent
For Example, a condition that has to go through a set of condition, and then find the value set on a condition within the condition prior

````
Here's the full syntax
SELECT 
RIGHT(s.Staff_ID, 3) AS [Staff Number],
Staff_FullName,
[Sales Transaction Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), SalesDate, 107),
[Total Quantity] = SUM(Quantity)

FROM
STAFF s
JOIN
SalesTransaction st
ON s.Staff_ID = st.Staff_ID

WHERE 
Staff_Country = 'China' AND
len(Staff_FullName) = (SELECT max(len(Staff_FullName)) FROM STAFF)


GROUP BY
s.Staff_ID,
Staff_FullName,
SalesDate

ORDER BY SUM (Quantity) ASC ```

How can I make it so it checks the longest value within the USA column?
Thank you in advance.
````

Comment: This is not MySql code. Tag the database that you use.

Comment: yes this is for SQL server, but you have to provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Your database has the columns:
table STAFF:

id            (an Int)

Staff_Country (an String)

FullName      (an String)

Staff_Name    (an String)

You could use:

```sql
SELECT id,Staff_name,MAX(LEN(Full_Name)) 
FROM STAFF
WHERE Staff_Country = 'USA';
```

So in the end, is not necessary to use two where's

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add, but the table is STAFF

Comment: sorry, miss clicked send the first time.

Comment: It's been solved, I had to use order by len(Staff_FullName) desc, so it wouldn't get jumbled up, thank you!